# Agents do not enter the process Blocks

Tags: anylogic, agent, flowchart

I used enter blocks to bring pieces of equipment to the process but nothing happens! How can I push the equipment to enter the process? Can I use resource task start block instead of enter block?

[image]

Comment: please try to limit to 1 question, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Feel free to open several questions :) (and try to put some more effort in, show what research and trials you have done already!)

Comment: @Benjamin I have edited the question! I hope it is better now. Looking forward to hearing from you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to push them manually. Typically, you have an `Exit` block somewhere else in your model where agents leave a process flow. In it's "on exit" code box, you use `myEnterBlock.take(agent)` to push the agent into an `Enter` block.

See [help](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fprocessmodeling%2Fenter.html&resultof=%22%65%6E%74%65%72%22%20) article on it (and get into the habit of checking that first ;) ). It even has a link to a video :)

Also, always check existing example models first. Typically, there are models that already do what you need, there are many that use Exit/Enter blocks, for example :)

Comment: Many thanks @Benjamin. Actually there are not any Exit block before those Enter blocks in my model, so  I added the code to the agents' stateCharts. Interestingly, one of them worked and another one did not work! I will try to figure it out why one of them did not work! :)